# Perl file handle with scalar target and IPC::Open3

Tags: perl, asynchronous, filehandle

My task is to start a program from perl and keep control flow to the starting task as well as capturing the output of the program in scalar variables. The script should only use perl modules available in perl base package.

My first approach was

```
use POSIX;
use IPC::Open3;
use strict;

my ($invar, $outvar, $errvar, $in, $out, $err, $pid, $pidr);
open($in, "<",\$invar);
open($out, ">",\$outvar);
open($err, ">",\$errvar);
my $cmd = "sleep 5; echo Test; sleep 5; echo Test; sleep 5;";
$pid = open3($in, $out, $err, $cmd);
my $num = 0;
for($pidr = $pid; $pidr >= 0;)
{
  sleep(1) if ($pidr = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) >= 0;
  print "$num: $outvar" if $outvar;
  ++$num;
}
close($in);
close($out);
close($err);
```

When started nothing happens. The output of the started program does not go into `$outvar`. To test if my basic idea fails I tried this:

```
my $outvar = "";
my $out;
open($out, ">", \$outvar);
print $out "Test\n";
print "--1--\n$outvar";
print $out "Test2\n";
print "--2--\n$outvar";
```

which correctly outputs as expected:

```
--1--
Test
--2--
Test
Test2
```

The question is: Why does the above program not work as the test example and output the text which should be in `$outvar`?

A working solution is much more complex (when you add all the security checks left out for this example):

```
use POSIX;
use IPC::Open3;
use strict;

my ($invar, $outvar, $errvar, $in, $out, $err, $pid, $pidr);
open($in, "<",\$invar);
open($out, ">",\$outvar);
open($err, ">",\$errvar);
my $cmd = "sleep 5; echo Test; sleep 5; echo Test; sleep 5;";
$pid = open3($in, $out, $err, $cmd);
my $num = 0;
for($pidr = $pid; $pidr >= 0;)
{
  sleep(1) if ($pidr = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) >= 0;
  my $obits; vec($obits, fileno($out), 1) = 1;
  if(select($obits, undef, undef, 0) > 0)
  {
    my $buffer;
    sysread($out, $buffer, 10240);
    print "$num: $buffer" if $buffer;
  }
  ++$num;
}
close($in);
close($out);
close($err);
```

It correctly prints (as should do the first one as well in similar way):

```
5: Test
10: Test
```

For the examples I removed much of the error handling and the similar code for STDERR.

Comment: By the way, it's called a "file handle" (because it holds onto a system resource), not a "file handler" (since it doesn't handle anything since it's not code).

Answer (score 1):

`open($out, ">", \$outvar);` does not create a system file handle. You'll notice that `fileno($out)` is `-1`. One process can't write to another's memory, much less manipulate its variables, so the whole concept is flawed. Use [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run); they effectively implement the `select` loop for you. `open3` is far too low-level for most applications.

---

The second snippet works because `open3` is behaving as if `$in`, `$out` and `$err` are unopened handles. You might as well have done

```
$in = gensym();
$out = gensym();
$err = gensym();
```

But again, you should be using IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run. Your hand-rolled version suffers from some bugs, including one that can lead to a deadlock.

Comment: You text is very hard to understand, but after reading several times it became clear what you mean.IPC::Run3 and IPC::Run aren't useful, see the initial task description, second sentence.

Comment: Re "*You text is very hard to understand*", if there's something that isn;t clear, let me know and I'll explain further. I spoke in simple sentences, so I don't see where the problem is. /// I know that IPC::Run3 isn't useful for you, but I included it because you're not the only reader of this answer, and it's simpler than IPC::Run. IPC::Run, otoh, does meet your stated needs. (Use `start`+`pump`+`finish` instead of `run`.)

Comment: I changed your text a bit. It is possible to directly write variables across processes. I also tried testing threads:shared for the text variables. It is only not supported in this case.

Comment: @Dirk Stöcker, Don't replace someone's answer that explains why an approach isn't possible with a claim that it's simply not supported. I reverted your edit. Writing to a system file handle can't directly cause a variable to be changed in another process.

Comment: When should I edit posts?: To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning) - If you think that stating the concept of inter-thread/inter-thread data storage is flawed then ok. I simply though that was an bad wording of you. If you think that's impossible to access other thread or other process memory then it seems you still need to learn a bit.

Comment: 1) Exactly. Changing the post to say the opposite of what I said is not appropriate. 2) Your edit didn't mention inter-thread storage. It didn't mention threads at all. Are you conflating threads and processes? 3) All of a process's memory is shared by its threads, so "inter-thread storage" is just weird way of saying "storage".